# Phonegap/Cordova check for file with special chars

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to download the needed images on the first start of my app. I check if a file exists before downloading, but have a problem with some special characters. Spaces seem to be encoded automatically, but how do I for example check for a file named file:///data/data/de.test.app/files/data/img/Pre+ƒ-test.jpg? I check files (after I ensured the deviceready-Event triggered) with:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + path, function (fileEntry) {
                    defer.resolve(fileEntry); //File exists
                }, function () {
                    defer.reject(path); //File not found
                });
```

I tried

```
path = "file:///data/data/de.test.app/files/data/img/Pre+ƒ-test.jpg";
path = "file:///data/data/de.test.app/files/data/img/Pre%2B%C6%92-test.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your file plugin version? I had an similar issue with File plugin 1.3, and fixed with that:

```
public LocalFilesystemURL filesystemURLforLocalPath(String localPath) {
        LocalFilesystemURL localURL = null;
        int shortestFullPath = 0;

        for (Filesystem fs: filesystems) {
            if (fs != null) {
                //LocalFilesystemURL url = fs.URLforFilesystemPath(localPath);
                LocalFilesystemURL url = fs.URLforFilesystemPath(Uri.encode(localPath, "/"));
                if (url != null) {
                    if (localURL == null || (url.fullPath.length() < shortestFullPath)) {
                        localURL = url;
                        shortestFullPath = url.fullPath.length();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return localURL;
    }
```